# Text gets clipped horizontally [React-Native|Expo]

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to put some text down, but the text gets clipped in a weird way

Code:

```js
                    <View
                        style={{
                            // align items center
                            alignItems: "center",
                            // justify content center
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            paddingHorizontal: 20,
                            paddingTop: 20,
                        }}
                    >
                        <FontAwesome5
                            name="exclamation-triangle"
                            size={35}
                            color="#FF1654"
                        />
                        <Text
                            style={{
                                fontSize: 20,
                                textAlign: "center",
                                // Text gets clipped on new android versions
                            }}
                            textBreakStrategy="simple"
                        >
                            Let op!
                        </Text>
                    </View>
```

Output (only says "Let" instead of "Let op!"):
[image]

(This was tested on Android)

I have tried near to everything, searched on stackoverflow, added a `textBreakStrategy="simple"` which changed nothing.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine for me. Testing it on Android, iOS and Web. Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/text-break) to test it out.

Comment: Hey @Kartikey 
Have you tried testing it on a Galaxy S20+ (Android V13) it only happens on that version. I figured this out yesterday the hard way. On other devices (some also v13) it does work normally. I am kinda at a loss for words...